# Ansible Synchronize module stuck while testing

Tags: ansible

Goal: I'm trying to copy `/home/foo/certificates/*/{fullchain.cer,*.key}`
from one server (tower.example.com) to other nodes.

When trying the task with `verbose` options, it's stuck. Output logs can be found there (Ansible 2.5): https://gist.github.com/tristanbes/1be96509d4853d647a49d30259672779

```
- hosts: staging:web:tower:!tower.example.com
  gather_facts: yes
  become: yes
  become_user: foo
  tasks:
    - name: synchronize the certificates folder
      synchronize:
        src: "/home/foo/certificates/"
        dest: "{{ certificates_path }}/"
        rsync_opts:
          - "--include=fullchain.cer"
          - "--include=*.key"
      delegate_to: tower.example.com
```

I'm running this playbook on localhost.
What I except of this is to connect as `foo` on `tower.example.com` then, to ssh as `foo` to servers of groups `web` and `staging` to rsync push the content of the folder matching the filters.

- I can run other playbooks on tower.example.com
- I can connect on tower.example.com with my user and then `sudo -i && su foo` to foo.
- As foo, I can connect to other hosts as foo for servers under group web and staging.

What am I missing?

Comment: do you have `rsync` installed?

Comment: yes :) i had rsync installed

Comment: often in these cases, it's waiting for a password or accepting a host key or something. I don't see evidence for this here, but it may help you to track down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `tower.example.com` may not have ssh access to the other hosts. This would cause Ansible to get stuck as ssh is waiting for a password. You can fix this by

- generating a new ssh key on `tower.example.com` and authorizing it on the other hosts, and/or
- setting up [ssh-agent forwarding](https://www.calazan.com/using-ssh-agent-forwarding-with-ansible/).

Alternatively, you could fetch the certificates to a temp folder on `localhost` and copy them to the other hosts. This avoids the use of `delegate_to`, but is not as efficient as syncing the files directly between the remote hosts.